# Dynamically change tipTip text

Tags: javascript, ajax, plugins, tiptip

I have tipTip on some of my checkboxes.. 
Trying to toggle its text to something like 'activate \ deactivate' but can't find how to update tipTip's content. 
Anyone have advice on this?

Also was trying to use custom attr but that didn't help me

```
// add tooltip
$(".element").tipTip({ attribute: 'tooltip-content' });
...

// change tooltip
$(".element").attr('tooltip-content', 'new text')
```

*tipTip plugin page* http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this did the trick for me:

```
// change tooltip
$(".element").tipTip({ content: 'new text' });
```

It doesn't look very elegant and I am not sure what happens internally, if the whole tipTip is replaced, or just the content updated... but it works.

The problem ist that the tipTip plugin stores the content to display on creation in a variable named **org_title**. But it seems impossible to edit it from any external call.
Maybe you could do this with the help of an enter function on creation:

```
tipTip({enter: function(tip){/*update org_tilte here*/}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the plugin after including jQuery?

```
<script src="jquery.tipTip.minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: sure, 1st initialisation line works without problems